# How to fasten my android video streaming application

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

Hello guys is there any way or a codes to fasten a video streaming application, like they compress the video when uploaded.

Thanks a bunch for a help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the WebRTC standard and protocols for this venture.
https://webrtc.org/